# What are the implications of Flatcar Linux's root filesystem RAID limitations?

Tags: partition, raid, raid1, coreos

As described [here](https://docs.flatcar-linux.org/os/root-filesystem-placement/), not all partitions of Flatcar Linux's root filesystem support RAID 1

> Other system partitions, such as USR-A, USR-B, OEM, and EFI-SYSTEM,
> cannot be placed on a software RAID array

What are the implications of this? Suppose the root filesystem is configured with RAID 1, can either drive fail? Or if the drive containing the single copy of the above partitions fails, would the OS fail to function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with partitions like EFI or `/boot` and RAID is that UEFI and GRUB don't understand RAID metadata -- they need the partition superblock to be certain type (FAT in case of EFI) and if there are RAID metadata it will simply think the partition isn't EFI and won't use it.

This is usually solved by using MD RAID metadata version 0.90 -- in this version metadata are stored at the end of the block device so for all other purposes the partition still looks like EFI one and you just have two copies. I'm not familiar with Flatcar Linux, but from the linked documentation it doesn't look like it offers such option. But you might be able to configure this storage setup manually.

> Suppose the root filesystem is configured with RAID 1, can either drive fail? Or if the drive containing the single copy of the above partitions fails, would the OS fail to function?

Yes, if you have only one copy of the EFI partition and the drive fails, the system will fail to boot. You won't loose data, but you'll need to either reinstall the system or restore the EFI partition from a backup.